# Useeffect setstate missing dependency warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a question regarding a missing dependency warning.

I've got a GET request where I'd like to set the catch error state. However when setting the error it asks to add the setError in the dependency list. The dependency should only be the {value}, not the setError right?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (value.length === 3) {
      setLoading(true);
      axios
        .get(
          `https://url.com?search=${value}`
        )
        .then((res) => setCompanies(res.data.data))
        .then(() => setLoading(false))
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response.status === 500) {
            setError("something went wrong");
          }
        });
    }
  }, [value]);
```

Warning notification: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setError'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

Comment: It should answer all of your questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare setError() and error :

```
const [error,setError] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    if (value.length === 3) {
      setLoading(true);
      axios
        .get(
          `https://url.com?search=${value}`
        )
        .then((res) => setCompanies(res.data.data))
        .then(() => setLoading(false))
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response.status === 500) {
            setError("something went wrong");
          }
        });
    }
  }, [value]);
```

Comment: I guess he already declared them 

It's just that React want to add all the state including setter in the useEffect dependencies array

Comment: yes indeed, I already declared it above the effect :)